# Storing extra tile/carpet In my attic

Tags: attic, truss

I recently re-did my whole house flooring (carpet in bedrooms, tile everywhere else) and have some extra materials that I would like to save in case a tile chips/carpet needs repaired. My garage is already pretty full of camping gear/tools/cars and these are things I plan to rarely (if ever) access, which is why I want to store them in the attic.

My attic is unfinished (single story house) with engineered 2x4 trusses and blown-in insulation. Location is desert south west, so no snow loads to account for. My understanding is that the bottom chord of 2x4 trusses isn't designed to hold anything more than drywall/insulation/light fixtures, so my thought was that I would lay some OSB right on top of an interior wall so that the wall is what bears the weight rather than the bottom chord. I'm thinking we are talking probably 200lbs of carpet and tile, I was going to get some 7/16 OSB.

Is this a bad idea?

Comment: What the trusses are designed to hold depends on how they were designed. That's a reasonable guess, but may or may not apply to your specific trusses.

Comment: have you considered digging a hole outside and burying the extra tile.  Just wrap it in some plastic so it is easy to clean if you ever need to dig it up.  don't do that with the carpet though =)

Comment: Throw the carpet away unless you can come up with a scenario where you’ll actually use it.